# Map D3 year to x axis

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm attempting to convert a set of years to the xaxis, but the output is giving me a decimal value. Any idea why that is?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<body>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.9/d3.js"></script>
<div id="line"></div>

<script>

var margin = {top: 10, right: 80, bottom: 20, left: 80},
    width = 560 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 100 - margin.top - margin.bottom;


var svg = d3.select("#line").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)

    linechart = svg.append("g")
                      .attr('id', 'removableLineChart')
                      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

      var years = [{year: 2008}, 
                   {year: 2009}, 
                   {year: 2010}, 
                   {year: 2011}, 
                   {year: 2012}];


      var x = d3.time.scale().domain(d3.extent(years, function(d){return d.year})).range([0, width]);
      var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x);

    linechart.append("g")
        .call(xAxis);
</script>
</body>
```

I expect x axis should show the years, but instead it shows the values .008,.009,.010,.011, .012

I'm not sure why this is and how to change it to show the years

Answer (score 0, accepted):

D3 time scale usually works with Date objects, but if you want to use years only, you can chain `tickFormat()` to your x-axis:

```
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).tickFormat(d3.time.format("%Y"));
```

And when assigning the domain to your x scale, map your dataset to create Date objects from `year`:

```
var x = d3.time.scale().domain(d3.extent(years, function(d) {
  return new Date(parseInt(d.year), 0);
})).range([0, width]);
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).tickFormat(d3.time.format("%Y")).ticks(years.length);
```

[Here's a pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NOREXN) with the x-axis displaying the years.